# How to reduce binwidth in geom_bar for one single bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to get a side-by-side bar plot using ggplot's `geom_bar()`. Here's some sample data I made up for replication purposes:

```
dat <- data.frame("x"=c(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),5)),
                  "by"=c(NA,0,0,0,0,NA,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I want to plot "x" grouped by "by". Now, because I don't need to plot `NA` values, I filtered for `!is.na(by)`)

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- filter(dat, !is.na(by))
```

Now for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, fill=as.factor(by))) + geom_bar(position="dodge") + theme_tufte()
```

This returns what I need; almost. Unfortunately, the first bar looks really weird, because it's binwidth is twice as high (due to the fact that there are no zeros in "by" for "x"==1).

Is there a way to reduce the binwidth for the first bar back to "normal"?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just figured out that you can manipulate the `binwidth` argument using an `ifelse` statement.

```
...geom_bar(..., binwidth = ifelse("by"==1 & is.na("x"), .5, 1)))
```

So if you play around with this, it will work. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this. Precalculate the table and use `geom_col`.

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(table(dat)), aes(x = x, y = Freq, fill = by)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]